# json_encode в PHP не экранирует кавычки

Tags: json, php

выполняю следующий код

```
mysql_connect("localhost","ххх","ххх");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_select_db("ххх");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from graph");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
//$str = str_replace(""","\"",$output);
echo json_encode($output);
mysql_close();
```

в ответ получаю строку с неэкранированными кавычками... как заэкранировать? как видно из кода, были предприняты попытки подмены через str_replace, но он тоже не сработал..

Comment: addslashes()?

mysql_real_escape_string()?

Comment: спасибо! сейчас попробую. я с PHP знаком максимум неделю...

Comment: Если знакомы с PHP не давно, советую прочитать справочник стандартных функций. Очень полезная вещь, поверьте :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace()` XDD) если облюбовали экранировать так то:

`$str = str_replace("'", "\'", $output);`

или

`$str = str_replace('"', '\"', $output);`

или лучше

`$str = str_replace(array("'", '"'), array("\'", '\"'), $output);`

но правильнее ответ от [[@Ёхарный Бабай](/users/2636/%D1%91%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9)](/users/2636/%D1%91%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9)

Comment: Снова кто-то мой коммент ответом сделал, подстава? Ребятки, если я считаю что **ЭТО** лучше написать в коммент, то не нужно его делать ответом. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

Все символы " кодируются в \u0022. Доступна начиная с PHP 5.3.0.